# React-router Webpack HMR. The root route must render a single element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-hmr

I am trying to figure out how the react-router works inside the AppContainer when HMR is enable and stuck upon the following error. Can you please explain what the hack is going on?

> Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
// AppContainer is a necessary wrapper component for HMR

import Routes from './routes/index';
const MOUNT_APP = document.getElementById('root');

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Routes />
    </AppContainer>,
    MOUNT_APP
  );
};

render();

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./routes/index', () => {
    render()
  });
}
```

**The route file is:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Home from './Home';
import SubView from './Sub';

const componentRoutes = {
  component   : Home,
  path        : '/',
  indexRoute  : SubView,
  childRoutes : [

  ]
}

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={componentRoutes} />
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

**HomeView Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

const HomeView = () => {
    <div>
      <h4>Welcome</h4>
    </div>
}

export default HomeView;
```

**HomeView Route:**

```
import HomeView from './components/SubView';

export default {
  component: HomeView
}
```

P.S: SubView is equal to HomeView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return one element from the component. Right now your component for `HomeView` looks like this:

```
const HomeView = () => {
    <div>
      <h4>Welcome</h4>
    </div>
}
```

You need to return the markup instead of just put it in the function body like this:

```
const HomeView = () => {
    return (
         <div>
             <h4>Welcome</h4>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Hum4no1d thank you, I did try to wrap both of components into return statement, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your `HomeView` component does not return anything.  You need to wrap the inner jsx in `return ( ... )`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I did, but the error still remains.